# How to add sort by "Best Seller" in tool bar in product listing page?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to add Best Seller option in the **sort by** drop down on product listing page.

This will find the products which are sold most from that category and display them.I am not using any attribute for best seller.

I tried using this link http://pratikkhamar.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/magento-sort-by-best-seller-in-toolbar/

But I am getting error message when trying to sort by Best Seller.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using an extension. I've used in the past [this one](http://amasty.com/improved-sorting.html), and it worked great on CE and EE. It's not free. but it's not that expensive either. I think it would 'cost' more to build one than what you have to pay for it. beside sorting by best sellers, it has other nice sorting options.

---

<sub>I'm in no way associated with the extension provider. I've just used the extension and liked it.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

you can use this document to work with your code if it is useful to you

just of throw [this link](http://pratikkhamar.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/magento-sort-by-best-seller-in-toolbar/)

Also here is extention which is free you just have to change naming convention to manage in your application look at this [exention](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/16824/)

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: I have already tried same link shared by you.But it is not working.